# str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

when i want to create a new user i got this error

```
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

here is a  full code of view.py

```
    from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    def register_page(request):
        signup_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {"signup_form": signup_form}
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            print(signup_form.cleaned_data)
            username = signup_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            new_user = user.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            print(new_user)
        return render(request, "auth/signup.html", context)
```

here is a code of forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control","placeholder": "your username"}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control',"placeholder": "your Password"}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control',"placeholder": "your Password"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm possword', 
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
    "placeholder": "your Password"}))
    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        qs = user.objects.filter(username=username)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('username already exists')
        return username
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = user.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('email already exists')
        return email
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password2 != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be matched")
        return data
```

here is all the code now please help to to solve this error. but when i remove validation from email fields the code run successfully

Comment: Please add your full form code as well.

Comment: It means your `signup_form.cleaned_data` is a string object and you cannot perform `get` operation on it. Pls add full code

Comment: Without knowing what the class `RegisterForm` is or does, it is hard to say exactly. But it is clear that when you call its method `.cleaned_data`, you get a string back, and not a form object that you seem to expect. Does `signup_form` maybe have a `.get` method?

Comment: seems that you are not calling post method in form so None is coming in form that python consider as a string.Anyway if you can share you html and form we can work on it.

Comment: @VIVEKVIKASH now check i shared full code

Answer (score 1):

Is the line `return email` in there a mistake? You have `return` in there twice.

```py
qs = user.objects.filter(email=email)
if qs.exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError('email already exists')
return email # <--- THIS LINE!
password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
if password2 != password:
   raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be matched")
return data
```

That could be your issue because you're returning a string and not an object that the `clean()` method expects.